# Can't add a UISplitView as a Tab Item in IB?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, interface-builder, ipad

Is there a reason why I can't add a UISplitviewController as the child of a UITabBarController in Interface Builder?

I realize I could do this programatically, but all of a sudden I'm questioning if this is a legit way to go.

This is what I'm planning on doing:

- Create a Master View Controller (UITableViewController with accompanying NIB)
- Create a Detail View Controller (UIViewController with accompanying NIB)
- Subclass UISplitviewController
- Attached the above to my Tab Bar Controller instance in Interface Builder by adding a UIViewController instance as a child, then changing the class name to my splitviewCont subclass (in Interface Builder).

This sounds kind of boneheaded to me. Is there a "recommended" way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed ad nauseam in several questions here on Stack Overflow (e.g. in [one of my own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553454/migrating-a-tab-bar-based-iphone-project-to-ipad))

The bottom line: a `UISplitViewController` must be the root view of an app (or perhaps more specifically, a window). It can not live inside a `UITabBarController` or anything else. If you try to add it in Interface Builder, you will quickly see it can't be done. If you do it from code, you will get compile-time or run-time errors.

You can, however, put a tab bar inside the split view's master (left) side.